# How to generate an Access token for implicit flow in IBM API Management Beta

Tags: oauth

I'm working on OAuth implicit flow implementation with IBM API Management Beta version.Can anyone please tell me what is the process for generating an access token with an example or do I need to use curl command for access token ??? Any clear steps to follow OAuth implementation in IBM APIM Beta using any security scheme either Application flow/Implicit/Password flow is also helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow these curl for password flow:

1.) `curl -k -X POST -d "grant_type=password&&scope=your_API_scope&username=your_IBM_APIM_username&password=your_IBMAPIM_password&client_id=client_id" "token_endpoint_url"`

it gives access token ...copy the access token and save it in notepad.

2.) `curl -k -H "Authorization : Bearer your_Access_token" -X GET "api_url&client_id=a30124a6-6757-48d6-b979-cf11b701c72a"`

gives you data.